# Why does Entity Framework truncate string value while saving into database?

Tags: c#, string, entity-framework

I have a problem with Entity Framework, it's truncating a string value while saving into database

I have database column `Description nvarchar(max)` in SQL Server 2014, and a property like this on my model class:

```
public string Description { get; set; }
```

I used this code to insert into database

```
db.EnitityName.Add(object);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Normally it works to save records, there is no problem, but when string exceeds more than 40k characters in `Description` property, it's saved value is truncated to the last characters from 40k to above.

E.g we have a 50k characters string, it saves only the first 40k characters and truncates the last 10k characters.

Is there something I did wrong, or does Entity Framework have a limitation on the string length, or database limitation in nvarchar(max)?

Please help me, I appreciate your valuable time in advance.

Thanks

Comment: How do you determine the rest is lost? There is no limitation in EF for string lengths.

Comment: thanks, good point, when i see database value its not complete string, its truncated. that is the problem, if i send 2-3k character string its save all in Database, you may get better idea now.

Comment: But how do you check for it? Querying database directly with a tool? Another C# code? Something else? What does simply asking for the length do?

Comment: by using select statement in sql query or directly open in database. both way i check.

Comment: Are you using database first or code first?

Comment: i am using code first.

Comment: What is the datatype and size of the field of database table generated by EF for your entity?

Comment: i used nvarchar(max)

Comment: Are you selected in Sql Server Management studio? that does have a length limit on things you select. try `select len(Description) from EnitityName` and check the size that way.

Comment: its good, i just checked this way, its characters size 51k, it means it saved all data into table, what can be the problem, but when save all data into text file by DB column, its 290kb size. mean, before to save its size is 51k after saving its size 290k, its the html editor data, is there a problem in EF.  thanks @Scott

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, but it turned out to be SQL Server Management Studio truncating the data, not Entity Framework (as [Scott Chamberlain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80274/scott-chamberlain) said in the comments). Change it by going to Query->Query Options):

[image]

Comment: Had similar issue. Was saving some 356k chars to a column and when queried - we'd also just see ~65XXX chars. Above fix works perfectly. Thanks